# highcharts-export-server with highcharts-regression plugin in a node module throws an error

Tags: highcharts

I've installed `highcharts-export-server` and the `highcharts-regression` plugin via npm. These are both installed in my project directory locally. I am using the exporter via a node module. Without the plugin, this all works and is exporting the image. Except, when I include the `highcharts-regression` plugin I get an error stating "Cannot read property 'data' of undefined".

I'm setting the `resources` property on the options object for the exporter parameters as a json string with a files property.

Here's my module:

```js
const exporter = require('highcharts-export-server');
module.exports = (callback, classRates) =>
{
    var exportSettings = {
        resources: "{ \"files\": \"https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/highcharts-regression@2.2.0/highcharts-regression.min.js\" }",
        type: 'png',
        options: {
            title: {
                text: 'My Chart'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "Mar", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
            },
            series: [
                {
                    regresssion: true,
                    regressionSettings: {name:"reg", type: 'linear'},
                    type: 'line',
                    data: [[1, 1], [2, 3], [3, 2], [4,4]]
                },
                {
                    type: 'line',
                    data: [5, 3, 4, 2]
                }
            ]
        }
    };

    exporter.initPool();
    exporter.export(exportSettings, function (err, res)
    {
        callback(null, res.data);
        exporter.killPool();
        process.exit(1);
    });

};
```

I also read about setting a resource path in the `node_modules/highcharts-export-server/build.js` file. But I'm not sure which array to put it in.

How do I include this plugin?

UPDATE: Is there a way to get the highcharts instance from the exporter? That way I can import the `highcharts-regression` plugin myself and initialize it before starting the export.

Comment: UPDATE: I've moved the reference to the highcharts-regression.js file to build.js and placed it in the `cdnAdditional` array. Now I get a different error: `an error occured when rendering the chart: SyntaxError: Unexpected token S in JSON at position 0` and further down the call stack there is a different exception: `SyntaxError: Use of reserved word 'let' in strict mode`. So I am now clueless.

Comment: UPDATE 2: I removed the plugin from build.js because I realized that I didn't use array syntax in the resources option (`resources: "{ \"files\": [\"https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/highcharts-regression@2.2.0/highcharts-regression.min.js\"] }"`), so I updated that in my module, and it is still throwing the same  error about `reading property data of undefined`.

Comment: UPDATE 3: added --allowCodeExecution and now the process just freezes. This shouldn't be so hard.

Comment: UPDATE 4:  I added `allowCodeExecution: true`  to the options object and had to get rid of the array syntax in the `resources` property. That got past update #3 above and now I get no errors and just don't see the trend line.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I got it working.

First adding `allowCodeExecution` helped.
But then once I started debugging the `highcharts-export-server` code in node, I found that there was an exception being thrown by phantomjs when evaluating (by way of `injectJs`) within `highcharts-regression.js`.

That module uses `for (let i=...`. Turns out the `let` keyword is not supported by phantomjs. This was only used on one line in the whole module, so I created a local copy and edited it to `for (var i=...` and that fixed that problem.

Now I'm getting my trend line.

But then I also have a "sma" series on the same chart. So I had to edit the `node_modules/highcharts-export-server/build.js` file and add `stock/{{version}}/indicators/indicators.js` as a `cdnAdditional` entry.
If you google how to add extra highcharts modules you will find details on how to do this -- on their forum. Basically you edit `build.js` then run `node build.js` from the root of where you have the `highcharts-export-server` installed by npm (or where you cloned it).

Note that the `resources.files` property wants a string of well formed *JSON*. It needs to be a comma separated list of filesystem paths or URIs (that start with http). This property does not want an array of strings. Just a singe string.